# Google Stacked Bar chart not displayed when data is omitted

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I am trying to implement google charts in my project.

Where I want to display marks of last x tests on bar graph.

But the issue is, user can take any number of subjects for the test like only Math and History.So I only want to show that subjects in a bar chart.

I can not display 0 since "0" might infer that user got 0 marks in that subject. I just want to include those subjects which the user gives test for.

Is this possible in google Chart or any other library ?

Here is the code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi">        </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Math', 'Science', 'History', 'Geography', { role:     'annotation' } ],
        ['#1', 10, 24, 20,  ''],
        ['#2', 16, 22, 23,  ''],
        ['#3', 28, 19, 29,  '']
      ]);

      var options = {
        width: 600,
        height: 400,
        legend: { position: 'top', maxLines: 3 },
        bar: { groupWidth: '75%' },
        isStacked: true
      };

        var chart = new     google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I tried morris.js, but I was unsuccessful.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!